# How to set the profile when running the s3cmd sync command

Tags: s3cmd

When I use aws sync, I can set the profile by doimg

```
aws sync ./test s3://test --profile stage
```

The profile matches to a set of credentials. I have different credentials for each profile.

How can I use the s3cmd sync command and set a profile as I do with aws sync?

Answer (score 13):

It is easy, just use the `-c` option to select the "configuration" that you want to use.

Example:

```
 s3cmd -c my_stage_config sync test s3://test
```

The default configuration (created with `--configure`) is stored inside the `~/.s3cfg` file.

You can copy it to new files to create different configuration profiles.

Comment: but what's the purpose of the [default] line in .s3cfg? for aws cli I can configure the profile in this line. Then I can use this profile with --profile. So for what purpose this line exists in s3cmd configuration when I can not use profiles?

Comment: To answer ChampS, there's a |default] section because it's necessary to make the file a valid INI file but it has no other purpose. It's indeed quite confusing though.

Comment: agreed - using profiles is so useful when dealing with a variety of accounts.  different files is a pain, but not the end of the world.

Answer (score 1):

Create a profile under the name `default`, and `export AWS_CREDENTIAL_FILE=~/.aws/credentials`. You should now be able to run `s3cmd`.
[reference](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/570)